# Python среднее значение по данным в каждой папке

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста, как оптимально решить следующее:

у меня есть папка, в этой папке 50 других папок с названием 350_audio,349_audio т.д.

В каждой папке есть около 200 аудио файлов.

Есть предсказание, какой файл отвечает за какую эмоцию.

Внимание вопрос: как сделать так, что вычислялся процент нахождения тех или иных эмоций не по всем папкам, а по каждой отдельной папке с файлами.

Например:
350_audio содержит 50% грусти, 50% радости
349_audio содержит 20 радости 80% тоски

Comment: скармливать на предсказание по 1 папке, а не все сразу ?

Comment: В model predict имеешь в виду?